# How to do this simple Responsive Layout using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Please take a look at this:

[removed]

When you resize the browser, it goes from 3 boxes on one line straight to 1 per line. Is there a way to make it go to 2 per line before going to 1?

Not sure if I am limited in layout options if I decide to use twitter bootstrap responsive grids like you sometimes are with other CSS grid frameworks (for example being limited to 960px wide designs with some).

Comment: It is sopposed to do so, it is the "responsive" idea. Think your example doing well.

Comment: Out of the box, bootstrap will not do that. The thing to keep in mind is that at that particular breakpoint, the responsive css isn't decreasing the number of columns in the grid, it's just ignoring the grid -- instead of it worrying about how much space in each `row` each `span` element should take up, it just bumps them all up to `width: 100%`. Trying to switch to 2 per line is probably doable by adding some of your own css and media queries, but it would probably be a little fiddly to do inside of bootstrap. Is this something that you actually really need, or just something you'd like?

Comment: @ZaidCrouch thanks but yes unfortunately I do, that's what the design demands.

Comment: The other issue you're going to run into with this is that even if you get 2 columns, it won't work properly unless you have an even number of columns per bootstrap `row`, as each row will still be a separate `block`. Here's [a live example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ugt6q/27/embedded/result/), which is a modified version of the jsfiddle from David's (excellent) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like Zaid's cautionary note, though if you really need to do this, here's something to get you started: [Live example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/Ugt6q/22/show/) and [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/Ugt6q/)

As your page layout becomes more complex and as you add more Bootstrap components, the list of exceptions you will have to add to the custom CSS with snowball, so probably good to keep it simple ;)

Good luck!

**CSS**

```
@media(min-width:481px) and (max-width:767px){

.row-fluid [class*="span"]{   /* for the above viewpoints, force spans to be 50% */ 
width:48.717948717948715%;

float:left;
}

.row-fluid .span12{    /* override so span12 is full width */
width:100%;
margin-right:0 !important;
}


.row-fluid [class*="span"]:first-child {
margin-left: 0;
 margin-right: 2.5109110747408616%;
}

.row-fluid [class*="span"]:last-child {
float:right;
}

}
```

Comment: Why have you specified width as `width:48.717948717948715%;` instead of `50%` for `.row-fluid [class*="span"]`

Comment: @ikartik90, this question related to Bootstrap 2.3. If you inspect the CSS for Bootstrap 2.3 and search for .span6 you'll see that the width is defined as 48.71...%. The remaining 1.29% was used for padding between the columns. This has changed with the current Bootstrap 3. If you inspect the CSS and search for col-md-6 you'll see that it is indeed now defined as 50%. I hope this helps!