# twitter bootstrap layout modifys when screen width changes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, html, fluid-layout

I'm trying to achieve something with Twitter Bootstrap, but I'm not sure of how to do it, and if it is possible (pretty sure it is, just have to know how :p ).

Basically what I would like to have is that when I'm in full screen My Layout is a four columns layout.

When I resize my screen to a smaller width, the layout should transform to a two columns layout.

Finally when on a phone size screen, having a one column layout.

For the phone, this is not a problem, knowing that twitter bootstrap stacks all the columns when screen size is between phone and tablet.

The problem is for the windows and tablet layout.

Let's say I do something like this :

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">test</div>
            <div class="span3">test2</div>
            <div class="span3">test3</div>
            <div class="span3">test4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then I have a four column layout until I resize to phone size and the div are stacked (when I use the bootstrap responsive).

I don't know if I made myself clear.

But if someone understands me, and can help, I would be glad to take all the advice on this point !

Edit : something like this would be great (but with twitter bootstrap if possible (I'm just trying to use it so it's basically to see how it works)) : http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/responsive-column-grid/

Thanks

Comment: You need to work with media queries to achieve your needs. Have a look at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive. Make use of the media queries     `/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }`

Comment: You have answered your question buddy. Check this link http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-column-layouts

Comment: I found what I was looking for :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400148/how-to-do-this-simple-responsive-layout-using-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for : stackoverflow.com/questions/15400148/